# Create a template in html and php

Tags: php, html, session

How do I change the ONLY the content of a page but not the template around?

Let's say I have a user logged in and see his account information page. What if the page only needs to change only certain elements in it?

This is basically what I did:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user'] == 'stuff'){
?>

User account page with certain changes in its content (html)

<?php
} else {
?>

User account page that says "you need to login first" with the same template (html)

<?php
}
?>
```

So, there are no redirection here. How do I simplify this or there are no other way except this way?

Comment: You can use php to load the content part and the rest (header, menu etc.) separately. That involves both html and php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the header and footer separately.

The main content will change depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly code the templates. Then copy the code into a PHP variable - it'd be best to store it in some "templates.php" file, then just call to it. Next, just do `print $header;` and you're set.